# TP-Link router connected through WDS to an external access point

Tags: router

I'm having issues to connect a router using WDS to an external Access Point. This is how the network is working (red line indicates the issue):

[image]

1) Modem ZTE F660 is connected to internet using ISP configuration (no issues)
2) Archer C20 connected to ZTE using ethernet cable. (no issues, Wifi configured).
3) External Access Point (WA5210G) connected to Archer router using the little PON device (ethernet).
4) Router WR740N (this is the issue).

What I want is the WR740N to be connected to the WA5210G using WDS feature to expand the network to the rest of the house. Tried with both WPA2 and WEP security, same problem.

If I connect the WR740N to the Archer C20 using WDS it works perfectly, so the problem is when trying to connect the WR740N to the WA5210G.

This is how the devices are setup:
Archer C20
- WAN configured with ISP config (internet working ok)
- IP 192.168.0.1
- DHCP enabled
- Wireless 2.4ghz, SSID MiCasa2, Password WPA2 AES, Channel 1.
- WDS bridge disabled

TL-WA5210G
- Operation Mode: Access Point
- IP 192.168.0.252
- DHCP disabled
- Wireless 2.4ghz, SSID MiCasa2, Password WPA2 AES, Channel 1.
- WDS bridge disabled

TL-WR740N
- WAN (nothing configured)
- IP 192.168.0.253
- DHCP disabled
- Wireless 2.4ghz, SSID MiCasa2, Password WPA2 AES, Channel 1.
- WDS bridge (I clicked on survey and connected the WA5210G)

Result:
Archer C20 works perfect, internet working fine.
WA5210G works perfect, internet working fine.
WR740N no internet access, I can connect to the network but without internet access.

Comment: This is a complex config, with no real details for anyone to help you with. I'd suggest simplifying the problem. Remove components until you can identify the smallest configuration that exhibits the problem. Then, post more details about that scenario...if that alone doesn't lead you to the problem.  Also, please don't link to images. They can't be indexed/searched, and can go bad in the future. Frankly, an ASCII art diagram would be more useful here.

Comment: As I mentioned I was able to identify that the problem is when connecting WR740N to the WA5210G via WDS. How can I reduce the scenario?

Comment: If those are the only two components in the scenario, then don't even mention/show all the others. (And, it's hard to follow when you call everything by model numbers. After identifying them the first time, just say, router/access point/modem, etc.)